# Rails/Angular app works perfectly locally but I'm getting a 500 Server Error on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, deployment

I have a nice little rails angular app that is working great locally, but now that I am trying to deploy to heroku, I'm having some problems. Namely, when I try making a POST request (through ajax), I get back and internal server error as a response({"status":"500","error":"Internal Server Error"}). It's really driving me crazy, it seems that it's preventing the info I want to get into my database from getting there, I've tried doing the suggestions on some of the other SO threads and nothing seems to work. Doubly confusing because it works perfectly on the local host. The heroku logs for the event are here:

```
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497826+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497831+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.1.4 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:9878
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497833+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497835+00:00 app[web.1]: => Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497836+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497838+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:27:51.885672 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 184.73.44.87 at 2014-09-23 04:27:51 +0000
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497840+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:27:51.988811 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by PagesController#index as */*
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497841+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:27:52.039041 #2]  INFO -- : Redirected to http://hidden-lowlands-5596.herokuapp.com/users/sign_in
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497843+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:27:52.039888 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 302 Found in 51ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497845+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:27:52.072805 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 184.73.44.87 at 2014-09-23 04:27:52 +0000
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497846+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:27:52.077594 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as */*
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497848+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:27:52.128662 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (14.9ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497849+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:27:52.180470 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 103ms (Views: 70.2ms | ActiveRecord: 13.0ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497851+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:29:23.691686 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 24.6.253.209 at 2014-09-23 04:29:23 +0000
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497852+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:29:23.695622 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497854+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:23.701573 #2] DEBUG -- :   User Load (2.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497855+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:29:23.706305 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered pages/index.html within layouts/application (1.3ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497857+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:29:23.707351 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 5.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497858+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.125810 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/articles" for 24.6.253.209 at 2014-09-23 04:29:25 +0000
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497860+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.130961 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by ArticlesController#index as JSON
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497863+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.133835 #2] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497864+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.159063 #2] DEBUG -- :   Feed Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "feeds".* FROM "feeds" INNER JOIN "subscriptions" ON "feeds"."id" = "subscriptions"."feed_id" WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.523076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/feeds" host=hidden-lowlands-5596.herokuapp.com request_id=f4e81159-eb5a-4115-9f35-3f666527d781 fwd="24.6.253.209" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=35ms status=304 bytes=1028
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497865+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.179293 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 10]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497867+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.184538 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (4.7ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 11]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497869+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.186052 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 12]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497878+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.187533 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 13]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497879+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.188925 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 14]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497881+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.190294 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 15]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497882+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.192010 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 16]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497884+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.193307 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 17]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497885+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.194673 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 18]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497891+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.196031 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 19]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497892+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.199035 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (2.5ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 20]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497894+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:29:25.199882 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 69ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 28.5ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497895+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:09.983278 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 24.6.253.209 at 2014-09-23 04:30:09 +0000
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497897+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:09.987649 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497898+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:09.990690 #2] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497900+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:09.993971 #2]  INFO -- :   Rendered pages/index.html within layouts/application (0.5ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497901+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:09.994855 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 7ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497902+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.918573 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/articles" for 24.6.253.209 at 2014-09-23 04:30:10 +0000
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497904+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.922422 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by ArticlesController#index as JSON
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497905+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.925552 #2] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497907+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.929624 #2] DEBUG -- :   Feed Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "feeds".* FROM "feeds" INNER JOIN "subscriptions" ON "feeds"."id" = "subscriptions"."feed_id" WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497909+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.936177 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 10]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497910+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.937606 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 11]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497912+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.939658 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 12]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497913+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.941542 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 13]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497932+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.943625 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 14]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497933+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.944958 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 15]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497935+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.946202 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 16]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497936+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.947584 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 17]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497938+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.949194 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 18]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497940+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.950493 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 19]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497941+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.951773 #2] DEBUG -- :   Article Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles"  WHERE "articles"."feed_id" = $1  [["feed_id", 20]]
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497943+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:10.952334 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 15.1ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497944+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:31.985603 #2]  INFO -- : Started POST "/feeds/search" for 24.6.253.209 at 2014-09-23 04:30:31 +0000
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497946+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:31.993881 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by FeedsController#search as JSON
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497947+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:31.993977 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"url"=>"q", "feed"=>{"url"=>"q"}}
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497952+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:32.186407 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 192ms (Views: 0.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497954+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.487812 #2]  INFO -- : Started GET "/feeds" for 24.6.253.209 at 2014-09-23 04:30:37 +0000
2014-09-23T04:30:37.497955+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.497710 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by FeedsController#index as JSON
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601702+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.508654 #2] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601707+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.512314 #2] DEBUG -- :   Feed Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "feeds".* FROM "feeds" INNER JOIN "subscriptions" ON "feeds"."id" = "subscriptions"."feed_id" WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601709+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.517631 #2]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 20ms (Views: 6.1ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601711+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.779048 #2]  INFO -- : Started POST "/feeds/create" for 24.6.253.209 at 2014-09-23 04:30:37 +0000
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601713+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.802768 #2]  INFO -- : Processing by FeedsController#create as JSON
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601715+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.802879 #2]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"url"=>"feed/http://www.questionablecontent.net/QCRSS.xml", "feed"=>{"url"=>"feed/http://www.questionablecontent.net/QCRSS.xml"}}
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601717+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.977191 #2] DEBUG -- :   Feed Load (8.1ms)  SELECT  "feeds".* FROM "feeds"  WHERE "feeds"."feedly_feed_id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601719+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.981727 #2] DEBUG -- :    (2.8ms)  BEGIN
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601721+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:37.994355 #2] DEBUG -- :   Feed Exists (9.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "feeds"  WHERE "feeds"."feedly_feed_id" = 'feed/http://www.questionablecontent.net/QCRSS.xml' LIMIT 1
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601723+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:38.006709 #2] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "feeds" ("created_at", "description", "feedly_feed_id", "name", "num_subscribers", "topics", "updated_at", "url") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-09-23 04:30:37.994655"], ["description", "Deathmøle Jacques' head takes up the bottom half of the panel, with his words taking up the top half. He is not concerned about the life of his friend."], ["feedly_feed_id", "feed/http://www.questionablecontent.net/QCRSS.xml"], ["name", "QC RSS"], ["num_subscribers", 50874], ["topics", "comics,webcomics,web comics,fun,humor"], ["updated_at", "2014-09-23 04:30:37.994655"], ["url", "http://www.questionablecontent.net"]]
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601741+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:38.011917 #2] DEBUG -- :    (4.7ms)  COMMIT
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601743+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:38.016273 #2] DEBUG -- :   User Load (3.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601744+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:38.019696 #2] DEBUG -- :    (1.9ms)  BEGIN
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601746+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:38.083515 #2] DEBUG -- :   SQL (2.8ms)  INSERT INTO "subscriptions" ("created_at", "feed_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-09-23 04:30:38.049168"], ["feed_id", 21], ["updated_at", "2014-09-23 04:30:38.049168"], ["user_id", 1]]
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601747+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:38.093502 #2] DEBUG -- :    (7.6ms)  COMMIT
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601749+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2014-09-23T04:30:38.396551 #2] DEBUG -- :   Feed Load (9.5ms)  SELECT  "feeds".* FROM "feeds"  WHERE "feeds"."feedly_feed_id" = 'feed/http://www.questionablecontent.net/QCRSS.xml' LIMIT 1
2014-09-23T04:30:38.601751+00:00 app[web.1]: #<Article id: nil, feed_id: nil, canonical_url: nil, site_url: nil, visual_url: nil, visual_height: nil, visual_width: nil, author: nil, title: nil, keywords: nil, summary: nil, feedly_id: nil, published: nil, fb_share_count: nil, fb_like_count: nil, fb_comment_count: nil, twitter_count: nil, reddit_score: nil, reddit_comment_count: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, calculated_rank: nil>
2014-09-23T04:30:38.773050+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/feeds/create" host=hidden-lowlands-5596.herokuapp.com request_id=9c3683ee-dabc-4e34-bfb0-c309dc547596 fwd="24.6.253.209" dyno=web.1 connect=289ms service=1018ms status=500 bytes=330
```

I'm really stumped on this one, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: First thing is to get some detailed logs from Heroku. Make sure you have these (or edit the existing entries to be like these) `config.log_level = :debug` and `config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` in your `production.rb` config file

Comment: I'm not seeing the 500 status - is it in these logs? Nevermind..bottom

Comment: Looks like all your params are nil - do you have any validations? Can you post your form and controller action?

Comment: Did you also remember to change to this: **config.serve_static_assets = true** in the config/environments/production.rb file, in order to serve assets properly on Heroku?

Comment: Yes static_assets are true and settheline, those are only nil value because i p'd out the new Article object before I put values in. Been looking for a bug this whole time and I can't find one and I'm skeptical there's even one in there, as it works perfectly on the local server :(